# Eclipse tab color setting not working (GUI options)

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtk, themes

I updated Eclipse to 4.2.0 (I'm running Archlinux). Eclipse seems to be not taking its own parameters:
[image: See the Preview section]

Note how the preview is showing correctly, but the main interface is showing this:

[image: Tab not readable]

Any advice on how to solve this?

I'm using a dark theme in my GTK. It used to show correctly before the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run into this trouble, try this little command:

```
#rename .css .not /usr/share/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/css/*.css
```

You will need to replace **4.2.2.v201302041200** with your Eclipse version number.

What I'm saying is, **remove or rename the theme CSS files**, you will be surprised of the neat, clean and simple interface Eclipse gets, and it will follow YOUR colour settings.

[image]

Notice how even the sidebar buttons got cleaner/non-bloated.

Edit:

For Ubuntu 13.10 the location of the CSS files is different:

```
/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4...
```

As Greg Kramida suggested, the command should be:

```
#rename -v 's/\.css/\.css\.not/g' /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000/css/*.css
```

**Updated 2014-09-19**

For those running the new version "Luna" 4.4.0 the directory has changed (platform became ui.themes) so the new command is:

```
#rename .css .not /usr/share/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.0.v20140604-1608/css/*.css
```

**Updated 2015-05-23**

As the version of eclipse keeps changing (at least in my linux distro) I found this command to be more useful:

```
# rename .css .not /usr/share/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes*/css/*.css
```

Comment: I spent most of yesterday trying to earn enough rep (I had 43, I did well!) just so I could say thanks, it says no "+1s" and stuff, but you are so helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I can confirm this behavior is still there as for `Eclipse 4.3`. I keep deleting those relentless `.css` files...

Comment: Just used this again, why do they have these CSS files?

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10, the above command didn't quite work, but this version of it worked: rename -v -n 's/\.css/\.css\.not/g' /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000/css/*.css

Comment: My apologies, in retrospective the -n option (no action) in the above should not be used. Had to state this publicly, since one person already had a problem with the above.

Comment: Some news. On 4.4.2, the location of the .css has moved to /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20140819-1717/css/. Aside: they finally have what seems like a decent built-in dark theme -- I recommend to have a look. The scroll bars seem to be wrong color, though.

Answer (score 2):

The UI look like the Eclipse 3.X stream. Did you switch the Preferences>Apparence Theme to classic? Try the GTK one to see if it's better.

However, there is still some issues with the Eclipse 4 css rendering.

If the first solution came out with no luck, what you can do is to create a plugin like this one : https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes

Then focus on the following properties on your css file

```
CTabItem {
}
CTabItem:selected { 
}
```

Where you can adjust the tabs colors.

Here are some resources:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/CSS
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/CSS/SWT_Mapping
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html

You may also find the Eclipse 4 CSS spy useful.

Ragards

Comment: I switched it to classic, because GTK is even worse, not displaying borders in the designated color. I'll try your ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Appearently Eclipse is listening to the stylesheet of winxp. Try adjusting that one:
http://raginggoblin.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/eclipse-4-juno-change-tab-color/

Comment: This solution worked for me.  Changed to <code>swt-selected-tabs-background: #000000 #111111 100%;</code> and <code>  swt-selected-tabs-background: #000000 #0000FF 100%;</code>